# Choose a group of 5 people to create a committee

Tags: combinatorics

We have 10 boys, 8 girls and 4 teachers.

We want to create a group of 5 with 1 teacher, 1 girl and the remaining 3 can be anybody of them.

So is it $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}\binom{10+(8-1)+(4-1)}{3}$$?

Tje first term for a teacher, the second for the girl and the last of the remaining three members of the group.

Comment: Be careful.  Your method counts selections with more than one girl multiple times, once for each way you could designate one of the girls in the group as the girl in the group.  The same is true for the teachers.  You could use an Inclusion-Exclusion argument to eliminate those selections which contain no girls or no teachers.

Comment: I got stuck right now. How do we eliminate those selections? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: You could do it directly by looking at the outcomes with exactly $1$ girl and exactly $4$ teachers, $1$ girl and $3$ teachers, $1$ girl and $2$ teachers, ... $2$ girls and $3$ teachers, $2$ girls and $2$ teachers, ... $4$ girls and $1$ teacher... This however is incredibly time consuming and not recommended.

Comment: As suggested, consider counting how many ways there are if we don't care about making sure we had at least one girl and at least one teacher.  Next, count how many of those outcomes were "bad" because we had no girls and remove it from the count we had earlier.  Further, count how many were bad because we had no teachers.  We then need to correct our count because we subtracted those outcomes who simultaneously had no girls *and* no teachers twice, so count those and add them back in so they were subtracted only once overall.

Comment: Do we take all minus all teacher minus all girls @N.F.Taussig

Comment: All if we don't care, minus if no girls, minus if no teachers, plus if no girls and no teachers

Comment: So is all minus no girls minus no teacher equal to $$\binom{10+8+4}{5}-\binom{10+4}{5}-\binom{10+8}{5}$$ @JMoravitz

Comment: Subtract the number of groups with no teachers and the number of groups with no girls from the total number of ways of selecting five people.  However, as JMoravitz said, that subtracts the number of groups with no teacher and no girls twice.  Since we only want to subtract them once, we must add the groups with only boys to the total.  I have to go to class.  If nobody else answers your question, I will address it later today.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you!! :-) @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your method is that, as pointed out in the comments, it counts groups with multiple girls or teachers multiple times. The way to go about solving this kind of problem is to first find the total number of groups of $5$, and then subtract the number of invalid groups. A group is invalid if it contains no girls or no teachers, so to find the number of invalid groups, we add the number of groups with no girls and the number of groups with no teachers, and then, since this double counts the groups with no girls and no teachers, we subtract the number of groups with only boys. This gives us:

$$\underbrace{\binom{22}{5}}_{\text{total}} - \underbrace{\binom{14}{5}}_{\text{no girls}} - \underbrace{\binom{18}{5}}_{\text{no teachers}} + \underbrace{\binom{10}{5}}_{\text{only boys}}$$

Comment: I got it!! Thank you!! :-)